# how can I write a list of pair?

Tags: c++, list, std-pair

I am currently trying to write a list of pairs. my code is :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

list<pair<string,char>> listPair;
list<pair<string,char>>::iterator it;
void printStars(list<pair<string,char>> listPair)
{

  for (it=listPair.begin(); it != listPair.end(); it++)
    cout << it->first <<" ";
  cout << endl;
}
int main()
{
    pair<string,char> mypair;
    listPair.push_back(make_pair("bib",'a'));
    listPair.push_back(make_pair("bob",'b'));
    for_each(listPair.begin(), listPair.end(), printStars);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation fails with:

```
error C2664: 'void (std::list<_Ty>)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' to 'std::list<_Ty>'
```

Can you please help me detect where exactly is the problem?

Comment: You didn't `#include <string>`.

Answer (score 2):

The functor you pass to `std::for_each` is expected to accept an element of the range you pass into `std::for_each`. Your last has `pair<string,char>` elements, so your functor should have a signature like: `void printStars(const pair<string,char>& elem)`.

In addition, to pass a plain function to `std::for_each` you need to use `std::ref` or (on an old compiler) `std::ptr_fun`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <string> // missing include
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

typedef list< pair<string,char> > list_t;
list_t listPair;
void printStars(list_t::reference x) // use a reference, otherwise you create a copy
{
  cout << x.first << " " << x.second << endl;
}
int main()
{
    pair<string,char> mypair;
    listPair.push_back(make_pair("bib",'a'));
    listPair.push_back(make_pair("bob",'b'));
    for_each(listPair.begin(), listPair.end(), std::ref(printStars)); // C++11
    for_each(listPair.begin(), listPair.end(), std::ptr_fun(&printStars)); // C++98

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, your `printStars()` expects a `list`, however `for_each` passes it each item, not the actual list:

Working code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

list<pair<string,char> > listPair;
list<pair<string,char> >::iterator it;
void printStars(const pair<string,char> & listPair){ //notice the &, so it would pass by reference and not make a new copy of the pair.
    cout << listPair.first << ' ';

}
int main() {
    pair<string,char> mypair;
    listPair.push_back(make_pair("bib",'a'));
    listPair.push_back(make_pair("bob",'b'));
    for_each(listPair.begin(), listPair.end(), printStars);
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```